# Same Components with different functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two sections in dom and both of their strcuture is same, be it class names etc..

one section has to get data from one api endpoint and other section has to get data from another end point. Please advise using the jquery.

```
<section class="headlines ratingsTable">
  Hello
</section>

<section class="headlines ratingsTable">
  Hi
</section>
```

Comment: `$('.headlines.ratingsTable')[0]` and `$('.headlines.ratingsTable')[1]`

Comment: This works but though it calls different api endpoints but I get same data on the view, Please advise